# ASP.NET Eval DataBinding C#

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, eval

You can do easily:

```
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptCityFriends" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptFriendsContainer_DataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgThumb" runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("FBUsuarioID","~/Friends.aspx?friendID={0}") %>' ImageUrl='<%# Eval("FBAvatarUsuario") %>' CssClass="imgThumbs" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

But if i want to pass two Querystrings?I.E:

```
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptCityFriends" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptFriendsContainer_DataBound">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgThumb" runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("FBUsuarioID","FBNomeUsuario","~/Friends.aspx?friendID={0}&nUser={1}") %>' ImageUrl='<%# Eval("FBAvatarUsuario") %>' CssClass="imgThumbs" />

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

How can I set two or more querystrings to an URL in "Eval DataBinding"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `String.Format()`, i.e.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCityFriends" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptFriendsContainer_DataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:ImageButton ID="imgThumb" runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%# String.Format("~/Friends.aspx?friendID={0}&nUser={1}", Eval("FBUsuarioID"), Eval("FBNomeUsuario")) %>' ImageUrl='<%# Eval("FBAvatarUsuario") %>' CssClass="imgThumbs" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Six years later and your answer is still being useful.